# Как получить подпись запроса в формате PKCS#7 detached signature

Tags: python, openssl

Вопрос в чём.

Нужно получить подпись запроса в формате PKCS#7 detached signature

Пишу на python 2.7

Для формирования подписи использую openssl.
Не знаю как верно получить PKCS#7 detached signature.
Вот один из вариантов, который я пробовал:

```
openssl_sign_cmd = [
    'openssl', 'dgst', '-sign', private_key_fn, '-binary',
    '-md_gost94', '-passin', 'stdin']

out, err = run_cmd(openssl_sign_cmd, input=private_key_pass + '\n' + text)
```

text: Подписываемый текст.
private_key_fn: Путь к PEM-файлу, содержащему частный ключ.
private_key_pass: Пароль к частному ключу.

Подскажите правильный механизм подписания сообщения.

Comment: вроде бы есть привязка (binding) библиотеки openssl в python-е: pyopenssl. почему бы не воспользоваться этой привязкой?

Comment: Пробовал использовать pyopenssl и m2crypto. Кажется легко получить подпись. Но ругается, что "unsupported algorithm". Говорят, что эти библиотеки не поддерживают гостовские алгоритмы. Позже нашел команду openssl, которая вроде подписывает в формате PKCS7 openssl smime -sign -binary -signer clcert.pem -inkey keynopass.pem -outform PEM -in request.xml -out request.xml.sign только верно ли..?

Comment: расшифруйте, пожалуйста, какой смысл вы вкладываете в вопрос «только верно ли?». вы не уверены, правильно ли работаете программа *openssl*?

Comment: используя pyOpenSSL как в этом ответе
https://stackoverflow.com/a/41553623/9239893

Answer (score 1):

Насколько я знаю, что бы работал md_gost94, нужно в конфиге openssl прописать:

```
// At the end of openssl.cnf add sections:
[openssl_def]
engines = engine_section

[engine_section]
gost = gost_section

[gost_section]
engine_id = gost
default_algorithms = ALL
dynamic_path = /usr/local/lib/engines/libgost.so        //or your $PREFIX/lib/engines/libgost.so
CRYPT_PARAMS = id-Gost28147-89-CryptoPro-A-ParamSet
```

Буквально пару-тройку недель назад была такая ошибка. Помогло https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10959771/openssl-and-gost-engine-issue-statically-linked